# Make asynchronous multi tasks on multi delegated hosts

Tags: ansible

I make *X times* an action delegated on the *group* of hosts. In this particular case, it drains a server on all sockets (aka instances) of all of my haproxies:

```
- name: HAproxy drain node
  haproxy:
    state: drain
    host: '{{ inventory_hostname }}'
    socket: "{{ item[1] }}"
    backend: "{{ backend_name | default(omit) }}"
    wait: yes
  delegate_to: "{{ item[0] }}"
  loop: "{{ groups[lb_haproxy]|product(socketstats.stdout_lines)|list }}"
  register: lbmemberstatus
```

It works but it's sequential. So I try to apply it the pattern *"fire and forget"* and wait : an async task with pool=0 and a second one *async_status* which loops on the results of the first task.

But I wasn't successful at getting it to work, in my case :

- the async jobs are distributed on all delegated hosts. So I wait for each these delegated hosts (first loop on the async_status task).
- And i wait for each jobs, getting it by looping on  *lbmemberstatus.results*. But in this list of jobs, jobs come from different delegated hosts.

```
- name: HAproxy drain node
  haproxy:
    state: drain
    host: '{{ inventory_hostname }}'
    socket: "{{ item[1] }}"
    backend: "{{ backend_name | default(omit) }}"
    wait: yes
    wait_retries: 12
  delegate_to: "{{ item[0] }}"
  loop: "{{ groups[lb_haproxy]|product(socketstats.stdout_lines)|list }}"
  register: lbmemberstatus
  async: 1000  # Maximum runtime in seconds.
  poll: 0  # Fire and continue (never poll)

- name: Wait for drain on all Haproxies
  async_status:
    jid: "{{ item[1].ansible_job_id }}"
  register: lbmemberstatus_poll_results
  until: lbmemberstatus_poll_results.finished
  retries: 300
  delegate_to: "{{ item[0] }}"
  loop: "{{ groups[lb_haproxy]|product(lbmemberstatus.results)|list }}"
```

Obviously, this example fails when the delegated hosts doesn't match to the host which runs the job.

How would you do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should iterate over `lbmemberstatus.results` but not construct a new product of `groups[lb_haproxy]` and `lbmemberstatus.results` which can of course mix up.

Registered result of a loop (in your case `lbmemberstatus.results`) always contains *original* item that was used for that particular iteration.

Try:

```
- debug:
    msg: "Host: {{ item.item[0], JobId: {{ item.ansible_job_id }}"
  loop: "{{ lbmemberstatus.results }}"
```

Here we have `item` as element of `lbmemberstatus.results` and `item.item` as element used for previous loop.

Comment: Thanks you. It works and still quite simple : 

```- name: Wait for drain on all Haproxies
  async_status:
    jid: "{{ item.ansible_job_id }}"
  register: lbmemberstatus_poll_results
  until: lbmemberstatus_poll_results.finished
  retries: 300
  delegate_to: "{{ item.item[0] }}"
  loop: "{{ lbmemberstatus.results }}"
```